# Add a new class to an existing JAR File(which contains source code)

Tags: java, android, jar, compilation, javac

I'll try to illustrate the problem as simple as I can.

I have a JAR file, which I extracted using Winrar. (The jar file contains an open source android library).
I want to modify this JAR file by adding a new class to the library.

So here are my steps:
First, I created a class using Eclipse and set the package name same as the android's library package name.
Second, I copied this java File to the folder of the other java files in the library.
Third, I tried to compile the JAVA file via the CMD using javac.

The path of the new java file and the other .JAVA and .CLASS files of the library is: `C:\com\example\core\`
The name of the new java file would be: `"MyNewClass.java"`
The command I run via the CMD is: `javac C:\com\example\core\MyNewClass.java`

But, during the compilation I get many errors saying: Cannot find symbols.

I've been looking up for a solution of this problem but couldn't figure how to solve it and make the new JAR File having another class that I created seperately.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you use a JAR explorer, you can just drag and drop the .class file into it. Make sure the package path exists and matches how it's declared in your class.

Comment: If it's an open source library you're working with, why not get the source code, add your modifications and recompile the whole shebang? That seems much more maintainable than mucking around with compiled code and various tools.

Comment: @idish: You're asking me how to get the source code for a library you don't mention by name? I haven't got a clue. You claimed it's open source, which means the source code should be available somewhere. If it isn't, it's not an open source library.

Comment: @MH. I suppose it is an open source lib. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: @MH. See the downloads section, there are multiple downloads with sources. But if I extract the JAR file, I get .JAVA + .CLASS Files and I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: @idish: Use git to clone the repository or hit "Download ZIP" on the righthand side of the page you linked. That will give you the full source of the project. After that, import it in your IDE. Then you'll be able to build the whole thing from scratch, make any adjustments/modifications you like, etc.

Comment: @MH. Ah.. I was struggling around with the last download which contains the library with the sources inside (.JAVA Files + .CLASS Files). There was a seperate download for the source code itself. You totally saved my life. Thank you so much. Maybe you could post it as an answer so I could accept it and +1. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per earlier comments:

Rather than trying to modify the JAR, you can get access to the full source code of the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library by cloning the repository using git or hitting "Download ZIP" on the righthand side of the page you linked.

Once you have the source, import the library in your IDE. From there on you'll be able to build the whole thing from scratch, make any adjustments/modifications you like, etc.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath might be wrong or there might be some mistake in package name.

When a Java program is being compiled the compiler it creates a list of all the identifiers in use. If it can't find what an identifier refers to it cannot complete the compilation. This is what the cannot find symbol error message is saying, it doesn't have enough information to piece together what the Java code wants to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
javac -cp com/* C:\com\example\core\MyNewClass.java
```

That should make the compiler aware of all the other classes under com/...